# show / hide link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide link with jquery, if the user clicks button first time, link will hide(by **adding class hidden**), but should show if clicks button second time (**remove class hidden**). its a collapse-toggle  feature. 
When I click button first time, it hides, but second time, does not work

HTML

```
     <!--BUTTON -->
<div class="sidebar-collapse" style="" id="sidebar-collapse">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-collapse-icon with-animation">

                    <i class="entypo-menu"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
 <a href="mysite_url" id="logo-title"> <br> My Site Name </a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    var logo_title = $('a#logo-title');
    $('div#sidebar-collapse').click(function(){
        logo_title.addClass('hidden-md hidden-lg cj_inspired');
        if($('div#sidebar-collapse').click() && logo_title.hasClass('cj_inspired') ){
            $('a#logo-title').removeClass('hidden-md hidden-lg cj_inspired');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide show link like this:

```js
$('div#sidebar-collapse').click(function(){
  if ( $("#logo-title").is(":visible") ) { 
    $("#logo-title").hide(); 
  } else if ( $("#logo-title").is(":hidden") ) { 
    $("#logo-title").show(); 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-collapse" style="" id="sidebar-collapse">
     <a href="#" class="sidebar-collapse-icon with-animation">
         Click               
         <i class="entypo-menu"></i>
     </a>
 </div>
 <a href="mysite_url" id="logo-title"> <br> My Site Name </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it :

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sidebar-collapse').click(function(){
 $('#logo-title').toggle();  
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-collapse" style="" id="sidebar-collapse">
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-collapse-icon with-animation">

                    <i class="entypo-menu"></i>Click
                </a>
            </div>
 <a href="mysite_url" id="logo-title"> <br> My Site Name </a>
```

this will be work..

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuerys `toggleClass()` to toggle a single class on/off of an element:

```
<script>
    var logo_title = $('a#logo-title');
    $('div#sidebar-collapse').click(function(){
        logo_title.toggleClass('hidden-md').toggleClass('hidden-lg').toggleClass('cj_inspired');
    });
</script>
```

It would be more elegant if you could use a single class to define the hidden styles.

Read more about `toggleClass()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).